# Can any one tell me the css selector for this expression:

Tags: css-selectors

xpath = a[contains(text(),'dbfsbdj')]

I have tried with a:contains('dbfsbdj') - but this is invalid ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't select an element by its text content with CSS.

If you want to use some JavaScript, you could do something like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52ws6ebz/)):

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

[].slice.call(paragraphs).forEach(function(p) {
    if(p.textContent.indexOf('World') > -1) {
        console.log(p);
    }
});

// => <p>World</p>
```

HTML:

```
<p>Hello</p>

<p>World</p>
```

You could then make a little function like this:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

console.log(contains(paragraphs, 'World')); // => [<p>World</p>]

function contains(_elements, text) {
    var elements = [];

    [].slice.call(_elements).forEach(function(p) {
        if(p.textContent.indexOf('World') > -1) {
            elements.push(p);
        }
    });   

    return elements; 
}
```